# How does syn::parse::ParseBuffer::peek() accept a type as an argument?

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

How are we able to pass type as an argument instead of turbofish to [`syn::parse::ParseBuffer::peek`](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.72/syn/parse/struct.ParseBuffer.html#method.peek)?

Methods are generally called like `input.parse::<Token![;]>()`. We pass types as generics but peek expects them as `input.peek(Token![;])`.

I wanted to know because if I create a type alias to `Token![;]`  like `type TokenAlias = Token![;]` and use it like `input.peek(TokenAlias)`,
I get the error:

```
expected value, found type alias `TokenAlias` can't use a type alias as a constructor
```

which would have made sense if `Token![;]` was also not allowed.

Why do I get this error when I use type alias?

Code with `TokenAlias`:

```rust
// COMPILE ERROR: expected value, found type alias `TokenAlias` can't use a type alias as a constructor

type TokenAlias = Token![;];

impl Parse for PathSegments {
    fn parse(input: ParseStream) -> Result<Self> {
        let mut segments = Punctuated::new();

        let first = parse_until(input, TokenAlias)?;
        segments.push_value(syn::parse2(first)?);

        while input.peek(TokenAlias) {
            segments.push_punct(input.parse()?);

            let next = parse_until(input, TokenAlias)?;
            segments.push_value(syn::parse2(next)?);
        }

        Ok(PathSegments { segments })
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b9494470df0ae7322a3fde1959bb3b1c)

Code with `Token![;]`:

```rust
// BUILDS SUCCESSFULLY

impl Parse for PathSegments {
    fn parse(input: ParseStream) -> Result<Self> {
        let mut segments = Punctuated::new();

        let first = parse_until(input, Token![;])?;
        segments.push_value(syn::parse2(first)?);

        while input.peek(Token![;]) {
            segments.push_punct(input.parse()?);

            let next = parse_until(input, Token![;])?;
            segments.push_value(syn::parse2(next)?);
        }

        Ok(PathSegments { segments })
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7378a8c9f5f5743a054f885295702927)

Following is the source code of `peek` from `syn`:

```rust
pub fn peek<T: Peek>(&self, token: T) -> bool {
    let _ = token;
    T::Token::peek(self.cursor())
}
```

[Source code](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.72/src/syn/parse.rs.html#580)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `peek` function accepts a token *value*, not a type.

The reason it accepts `Token[;]` is that it expands to an identifier that is the name of [a type](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.72/syn/token/struct.Semi.html), but also of a [global function](https://github.com/dtolnay/syn/blob/d4d3a4bff0b673401e36d92a7c8ad35fd37ad898/src/token.rs#L256) hidden from docs! Your type alias refers to the type, and attempting to construct a value using constructor syntax for unit-like structs makes the compiler complain that such syntax doesn't work for type aliases. (And even if it did, `Semi` is not a unit-like struct, so it wouldn't work for that type in particular.)

Comment: That is a pretty nice way to use unit struct. Although, when I see the docs of [`syn::token::Semi`](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.72/syn/token/struct.Semi.html), it does show a field in it named `spans`. Isn't that the type to which `Token![;]` expands?

Comment: @Mihir It appears `syn` is even sneakier than I thought, and defines both a type and a function called `Semi`, and it's the function that gets picked up by `peek()`. I've now amended the answer to explain the situation.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to check that too. When I tried assigning some wrong type to  `Semi`, It says, its type is [`fn(_) -> syn::token::Semi {syn::token::Semi::<_>}`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2dc1031cb1494e05e9d5845937e9978c)

Comment: @Mihir I saw that too, but it looked totally insane. Since the definition is behind a macro and the function is hidden from docs, it took a while to figure out what's going on.